# how to find next element of current element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hi i want to set a text into an span that is next to my current element.

```
<input type="text" class="myText" />
<span class="text-danger"></span>

<input type="text" class="myText" />
<span class="text-danger"></span>

<script>
    $(".myText").each(function(){
         $(this).siblings("span").eq(0).text("someText");   
    })
</script>
```

i want to see that text next to my input (span). but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "doesn't work"? Any error showing up? From the code-example, you noticed that the `<span>`s will only be updated once at the start? So if there is not content at that point, they will stay empty.

Comment: Work just fine https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/mgubdv1j/

Comment: actually i summarize my problem. this script works when submit button be clicked. and doesn't work means it doesn't show "sometext" in my span

Answer (score 0):

I think this would do what you want since there is no need to use siblings and eq

```
<script>
    $(".myText").each(function(){
         $(this).next("span.text-danger").text("someText");   
    })
</script>
```

Comment: The posted code in the question already work, this is an alternative not an answer

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the loop at all, and jquery has a `.next()` selector so just `$(".myText").next().text("someText");` will do the trick.

```js
$(".myText").next().text("someText");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="myText" />
<span class="text-danger"></span>

<input type="text" class="myText" />
<span class="text-danger"></span>
```

Is there any reason you need to select the `.myText` element first and then locate the next one?  You could just select `$('.text-danger')` directly

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nextElementSibling`

```js
$('.myText').on('input',function(){
  this.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = this.value
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="myText" />
<span class="text-danger"></span>

<input type="text" class="myText" />
<span class="text-danger"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

To select the next element, use next() function, for example, if you want to write input value in the span,you can use the following functions:

1. keyup() to execute a code each time you press a button:
   https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_keyup.asp
2. next() to select the next element of your input tag https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_next.asp
3. val() to get the input value 
   https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_val.asp

So your final code should be like that:

```html
  <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="3.2.1" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.2.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
 <input type="text" class="myText" />
  <span class="text-danger"></span>

  <input type="text" class="myText" />
  <span class="text-danger"></span>

  <script>
    $(".myText").keyup(function(){
    $(this).next().text($(this).val());
});
  </script>
```